# Allocate datatype on the stack

Tags: ats

`datatype` is used to create a non-linear type that will be allocated on the heap and `datavtype` for a linear type that will be allocated on the heap.

But, is there a version of `datatype` that will allocate on the stack?

Comment: The current compiler (patsopt) does not support allocating datatype values on the stack.

Comment: Even using `alloca` and the `*_unfold` of the variants?